# What are the few spell tomes that can only be found?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I’ve been playing for a while now and was wondering if there was any other spells not quest specific but spells that can only be found. Example: Bound Dagger and Equilibrium

Comment: Your question and content are asking two different things - are you wanting to know which spells are not quest specific (this would be the majority) or which can only be physically found in the world and not bought or learned elsewhere (only a small number of these exist)?

Comment: @KallumTanton techincally they asked non-quest, only loot spells. Pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

Including Dawnguard, Hearthfire and Dragonborn the following spells can only be found in the world in fixed* locations (see the links for location information):

- [Transmute](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Transmute)
- [Equilibrium](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Equilibrium)
- [Conjure Boneman](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjure_Boneman)
- [Conjure Mistman](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjure_Mistman)
- [Conjure Seeker](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Conjure_Seeker)
- [Conjure Wrathman](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjure_Wrathman)

* Conjure Seeker can be found anywhere in Apocrypha.

Minor point: Your example of [Bound Dagger](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Spells#Bound_Dagger) can only be bought therefor isn't a valid example.

Comment: Oof. Nice answer to include DLC content. I forgot about those conjuring spells tho.